# yum install php-devel amongst other commands returning problems

Tags: centos, php

I run `yum install php-devel` and it returns this.  Typically I'd just run it with --skip-broken, but when I do, it still doesn't do the trick.

```
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.29-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.29-2.w6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.w6
       Available: php55w-common-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.13-2.w6
       Installing: php55w-common-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.14-1.w6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

When run with `--skip-broken` it returns this at the end:

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:

```
 autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 pcre-devel-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-soap-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php55w-cli-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
 php55w-common-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
 php55w-devel-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
```

This problem has arisen with a few other similar commands when installing something related to php, except I've just done without them.

I need to install this for something I'm trying to do.  I do remember upgrading to PHP 5.4 and our entire infrastructure coming down due to it requiring PHP 5.3, so I downgraded as quick as possible to get everything back running and that may contribute to the issue.

If you have any idea why this is happening and how I could get the package on the system while remaining on PHP 5.3, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest thing to do at this point - get rid of the webtatic packages.

```
yum --disablerepo=webtatic distro-sync
```

Should get you on the right track for starters.

EDIT: how to disable webtatic permanently:

```
sed -i '/\[webtatic\]/,/^$/ s/\(enabled=\)1/\10/p' $(grep -rlF [webtatic] /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo)
```

And then do

```
yum distro-sync
```

and go over the results of
`package-cleanup --orphans` (or `yum list extras`)
to determine any other packages that might need removal.

Comment: Will do this tonight.  What do I do after that?  Will I still be on 5.3.3 or need to reinstall?

Comment: Don't _just_ disable it, remove it entirely. Then run `yum distro-sync` and `package-cleanup --orphans` to help identify leftover packages from that repo.

Comment: php-common on rhel6 is 5.3.3 so it should remain (or possibly reinstall from the rhel6 repo). Don't use `-y`, and go over what yum will do before you accept anything. possibly paste here the result before you commit (press y) so we can advise further. And yes - remove webtatic from your repo file so you don't have to disable it on every subsequent command.

Comment: Then do I just reinstall PHP?

Comment: I created a droplet on digitalocean, installed the webtatic repo along with php and a ton of packages, ran the command above and in the comments, removed php, and then reinstalled and it worked great.

I'll comment back results once I've done this on the real server.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue and resolve as below:

1. First, make sure which version of PHP you have, PHP 5.3, 5.4 or 5.5
2. Next, when you issue the command 'yum install php-devel'. Closely observe and see as which version of devel it is trying to install
3. Next, try to search the available repos as 'yum search php53' or `yum search php54` etc, based on your PHP version
4. You should be shown the list of Packages that are available.
5. Now, issue the command specifying the exact version that you are willing to install. Ex: `yum install php53_devel.x86_64` or `yum install php54w.x86_64` etc

The following SO question helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325109/cant-install-php-devel-on-centos

Answer (score 0):

> Typically I'd just run it with --skip-broken

So your system is now probably in an utterly messed up state. This extra 'webtatic' repo you use is likely related to that. I would at this point wipe the box and start from scratch.

Comment: That's definitely not an option.  I've only used that repo for PHP stuff.  Is there anyway to remove php along with the packages from that repo, uninstall it, and then reinstall it properly?

Comment: Yes, `rpm -qa | grep w6` should be a good indication of which packages come from that repo. Also get rid of the .repo file to avoid further madness from it.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep w6` returned nothing.

Comment: rpm -qa only returns name, not version, so w6 wouldn't show. `yum list installed | grep w6` OTOH...

Comment: Still returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install php-devel`